# How do I restrict the date popup to 12 months from start date?

Tags: datetime

I have a custom module where I set two date pop-ups.

```
$form['set_start_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('set start date'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);

$form['set_end_date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('set end date'),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

If I select 2017-04-12 as start date, the accepted end date should not be after 2018-04-12.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: No need to do custom code ,content type>managefield>edit date field ,where you can see Default date and Relative default value,set Default date=relative,Relative default value= -12 month

Comment: @Vikramfz16 That is for a content type; the OP is creating a form, so that setting would not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Method i used to restrict the date Pop-up to 12 months

```
$form['set_start_date'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('START DATE '),
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-12 months', 'max' => 'now' ),
      '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    ];


 $form['set_end_date'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('END DATE'),
      '#type' => 'date',
      '#attributes' => array('type'=> 'date', 'min'=> '-12 months', 'max' => 'now' ),
      '#date_date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
    ];


  $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Filter'),
    );

 return $form;
}
```